# Can't find the objects in array that are clearly states

Tags: discord.js

So i am trying to make a periodic table bot (Don't question i got bored), so I turned my spreadsheet of the info into a csv then used [this](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) to convert it to a json. My main code for my command is [here](https://pastebin.com/xdAhHKBP) and [this](https://pastebin.com/Nz6k8y34) is my json file. It won't work, before it was saying how element.find is not a function now it can't find the things in my array.

```
if(!element.find(i => i.Symbol === args) || !element.find(i => i["Atomic Number"] == args)){
        message.channel.send("Please use the command like this ``?pt (element symbol or atomic number)``")
        return
}
```

also it keeps sending the "Please use the command like this.." command when ever i try and call a number or symbol that should be in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your if statement. You're checking whether the array `element` does not contain an item with property `Symbol` being `args` OR property `Atomic Number` being `args`. Since no periodic element has the same value for both the Symbol and Atomic Number, the condition will always return false for at least one of the two statements.

The fix is quite simple, just change the `||` to `&&`. This way the if statement will check whether the array does not contain an item with `Symbol` being `args` AND does not contain an item with `Atomic Number` being `args`. If either one of the two returns true, the code in the if statement won't be called